# What does the "to" in "to spot" mean

Tags: to-infinitive

I don't understand which situation I've to use this usage of "to". What can be an interchangeable word for this?

> Having promised a large reward to the first man **to spot** land,
> Columbus claimed that he had seen the light.

Could the sentence be rephrased as:

> …the first man **who spotted** land

Comment: Yes, it can. This is a reasonably common usage in English. Try doing an Ngram search for _the first man to_ versus _the first man who_.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct about the meaning of the phrase. The following reference discusses using a *to-infinitive* to replace a relative clause that identifies something as unique, such as *first, second, last, only* etc:

[grammaring *to-infinitive to replace relative clause*](https://www.grammaring.com/the-to-infinitive-to-replace-a-relative-clause)

> A to-infinitive clause can replace a defining relative clause after ordinal numbers (the first, the second etc.), after superlatives (the best, the most beautiful etc.) and after next, last and only:

Answer (score 2):

Using "who spotted" would leave the meaning unchanged. But this use of an infinitive verb form is quite common and grammatically normal.

> - The price will be awarded to the first person **to break** the record.
> - He seemed ready to cry over this disappointment.
> - "I think it will be easy to finish this project today", he said confidently.
> - She was ready to sleep at this point.

This use of "to {verb}" means "to perform the action of {verb}ing".